# Is it possible to have autofocus on two input fields in the same page?

Tags: autofocus

I have one form in the header of a website, and the same form in a side area (that slides out) in the same website. Is it possible to have autofocus on both input fields. When I do this, both won't show up the cursor, but when I only add it to one (the header form) it works fine. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can have only one field with focus.

Comment: I have a little different case: I load part of page with ajax (popup) and want to set autofocus for different popups but in fact they both in one page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need more than 2 forms in your page, and while one form is visible other one should be hidden.

E.g. User name and password are in 2 different forms. First you will enter username, check in DB whether Username is correct, then show the other form, and the password field will be visible.